# Load data to zipkin with curl post request

Tags: curl, post, zipkin

I use zipking for testing with curl post.
Examples for post https://zipkin.io/zipkin-api/#/default/post_spans

```
$ curl -X POST "http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans" -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/json" -d "[ { \"traceId\": \"string\", \"name\": \"string\", \"parentId\": \"string\", \"id\": \"string\", \"kind\": \"CLIENT\", \"timestamp\": 0, \"duration\": 0, \"debug\": true, \"shared\": true, \"localEndpoint\": { \"serviceName\": \"string\", \"ipv4\": \"string\", \"ipv6\": \"string\", \"port\": 0 }, \"remoteEndpoint\": { \"serviceName\": \"string\", \"ipv4\": \"string\", \"ipv6\": \"string\", \"port\": 0 }, \"annotations\": [ { \"timestamp\": 0, \"value\": \"string\" } ], \"tags\": { \"additionalProp1\": \"string\", \"additionalProp2\": \"string\", \"additionalProp3\": \"string\" } }]"
```

503 Service Unavailable

zipkin in docker, logs in container:

> 2019-07-24 07:05:42.383 WARN 1 --- [orker-epoll-2-5]
>   z.s.i.BodyIsExceptionMessage : Unexpected error handling request.
>
> com.linecorp.armeria.common.stream.AbortedStreamException: null

I also tried example:

```
curl -vs localhost:9411/api/v1/spans -H'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Expect:' -d '[
  {
    "traceId": "5e1b76cb257aa6fd",
    "name": "app - root span",
    "id": "168ba9a2869c3ae1",
    "timestamp": 1473066067938000,
    "duration": 484655,
    "annotations": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1473066067938000,
        "value": "sr",
        "endpoint": {
          "serviceName": "app",
          "ipv4": "0.0.0.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1473066068422655,
        "value": "ss",
        "endpoint": {
          "serviceName": "app",
          "ipv4": "0.0.0.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "binaryAnnotations": []
  },
  {
    "traceId": "5e1b76cb257aa6fd",
    "name": "app test - get",
    "id": "fbbff4adc94c01cb",
    "parentId": "168ba9a2869c3ae1",
    "timestamp": 1473066067939000,
    "duration": 483823,
    "annotations": [],
    "binaryAnnotations": [
      {
        "key": "error",
        "value": "test",
        "endpoint": {
          "serviceName": "app",
          "ipv4": "0.0.0.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "lc",
        "value": "Application",
        "endpoint": {
          "serviceName": "app",
          "ipv4": "0.0.0.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]'
```

but I do not sees in web ui.

Answer (score 1):

I found examples from:
https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-lens/testdata

It works well.